# Blackmagic (BMPC 4K) colour moire removal

Tags: blackmagic, moire

Does anyone know a way to:

1. Prevent colour moire at time of capture
2. Remove colour moire in post (FCPX or Resolve)

BMPC 4K / ProRes422HQ / ISO 400 / 6500K / Film / 30fps

[image]

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to remove Moire in post. It's like having clipped audio. You might be able to hide it. But you won't be able to get rid of it.

Comment: Thanks - I'll have to hit Google some time and find out what causes it.

Comment: I believe it's debayering. Usually it's only on heavier patterns e.g. larger lines but I've never seen it on such fine detail. I would almost say this looks more like chromatic aberration which can be fixed in resolve I think but don't quote me on it. Some cameras don't have very good antialiasing filters or any at all and I believe the black magic is one of them. The benefits of not having one are usually extra sharpness.